# Some string comes along with URL

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I try to run the application the internet explorer loads my page with url like

http://localhost:1583/PMS/(S(gguhu4jtwv4waa45q5q2ehzk))/GenerateReport.aspx

And when I try to publish my site to the server, there too some string comes along with the url. Earlier it was working correctly.
Why this **(S(gguhu4jtwv4waa45q5q2ehzk))** comes with the url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your application is configured with [cookieless SessionIDs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx). When you access your site in a new browser you are creating a new session, hence a new id (that's the string you've highlighted above).

Comment: Yes. I didnt notice that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's session identifier, you're trying to use cookieless sessions.

Details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you use cookie less session so session key inserted in your url automatically.
Take a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx